# How to specify different first words in a line Python

Tags: python, string, line

I have a txt file with such lines:

```
місто Ясинуватського р-ну Донецької обл.#1#Авдіївка
м., ліва притока Інгул.#3#Аджамка (Аджимка, Аджинка
```

I have done this (Python 2.7):

```
for line in text.splitlines():
  if line.startswith(u'місто'):       
    before_keyword, after_keyword = line.rsplit(u'#',1)
    encoded=after_keyword.encode('cp1251')
    print encoded
```

How can I specify that my line should **starts** with **u"місто"** or **u"м."***?
I want my result to be:

```
Авдіївка

Аджамка (Аджимка, Аджинка
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a tuple of values to `str.startswith`:

```
if line.startswith((u'місто', u'м.')):
```

help on `str.startswith`:

```
startswith(...)
    S.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]]) -> bool
```

> Return True if `S` starts with the specified prefix, False otherwise.
>       With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
>       With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
>       **prefix can also be a tuple of strings to try**.

Comment: Thnx, you made my day)